# Exception in thread "main" java.ClassCastException: MomentOfInertia.triangle cannot be cast to Ix

Tags: java

everyone. I am a newbie of Java.
Here's the problem while I am learning abstract, implements

It can be compiled.
But after I type "java Ass", it gives me the following:

Exception in thread "main" java.ClassCastException: MomentOfInertia.triangle cannot be cast to Ix

There's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MomentOfInertia
{
    interface Ix{public double calcIx(double x, double y);}

    interface Iy{public double calcIy();}

    interface J{public double calcJ();}

    interface I extends Ix, Iy {}

    abstract class shape{public abstract void f();}

    class triangle extends shape implements I, J
    {
        public void f(){System.out.println("\n\nAbstract \'shape\'to triangle");}
        public double calcIx(double x, double y){return x*y*10;}
        //public double calcIy(){return 1;}
        //public double calcJ(){return 1;}
    }
}

class Ass
{

    public static void calc1(Ix a)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input2 = scan.nextInt();
        int input3 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n\t\'interface\' to Ix:" + a.calcIx(input2, input3));
    }
    //public static void calc2(Iy b){System.out.println("\n\t\'interface\' to Iy:" + b.calcIy());}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        System.out.println("\n\nHere is the demo of polymorphism");

        MomentOfInertia MoI = new MomentOfInertia();
        MomentOfInertia.triangle t = MoI.new triangle();
        calc1((Ix) t);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. The class of which you try to cast an instance to Ix, does not implement that interface. Therefore, there is no IS-A relationship, which is mandatory in order for such a cast to be possible.

```
class triangle extends shape implements I, J
```

which means, you can cast it to: shape, I and J, but not to Ix.

Comment: interface I extends Ix, Iy {} <--- Shouldn't I include Ix?

Comment: I don't understand something here... `interface I extends Ix, Iy` so `triangle` implements the `Ix` interface, isn't it ? And we also can cast it to all the super class of `shape` ;)